# How to put ArUco markers in Gazebo Classic

Tags: gazebo, pose, marker

The title says it all. I would like to test my robot's ArUco recognition and processing abilities by putting some markers around environments in classic Gazebo.

All the tutorials I see online seem to be for older versions of Gazebo and (frankly) use some very elaborate tricks.

What is the canonical way of adding a marker to Gazebo?

EDIT: My version of Gazebo is 11.10.2, by "older versions of Gazebo" I mean older versions of Gazebo classic specifically. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate the objects themselves what I found the easiest was to use [this repo](https://github.com/mikaelarguedas/gazebo_models) which takes in a bunch of images and outputs models that Gazebo<sup>1</sup> can understand. There is a [brief tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3fJwTL2O4g) for the repo on Youtube as well.

You then have to put those models in a folder that makes sense for your project and, **here's the key thing**:

Wherever those models are stored, **you have to put the folder they are in into the environment variable `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`.**

EXAMPLE:

Say my workspace is in `~/my_ws/` and inside there I have a folder called `mymodels`.

Then I would run this whenever I activate my ROS2 environment:

`export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:mymodels`

Along with other things like `source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash` etc.

One last thing: I had to go into the `model.sdf` file for each of the markers I generated and reduce its size. I don't know how the sizing in that repo is supposed to work but the marker objects it generated for me were enormous. Thankfully it's pretty easy to do in the scale tag.

Footnotes:

1: Gazebo Classic, in my case 11.10 on Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Humble

Answer (score 2):

[This forum post](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/27574/is-it-possible-to-create-an-aruco-marker-and-add-it-to-gazebo11/) and [this blog post](https://nlamprian.me/blog/software/ros/2020/01/27/visual-servoing-in-gazebo/) and corresponding [example model](https://github.com/nlamprian/grobot/tree/master/grobot_gazebo/models/aruco_marker) are pretty helpful.

This is just a simple [model](https://github.com/nlamprian/grobot/blob/78fd627990f743997138015d14e9059079e3044f/grobot_gazebo/models/aruco_marker/model.sdf#L3) defining a link which has a [front visual](https://github.com/nlamprian/grobot/blob/78fd627990f743997138015d14e9059079e3044f/grobot_gazebo/models/aruco_marker/model.sdf#L17-L31) and a [back visual](https://github.com/nlamprian/grobot/blob/78fd627990f743997138015d14e9059079e3044f/grobot_gazebo/models/aruco_marker/model.sdf#L33-L40). The front visual loads the aruco marker throug a [material script](https://github.com/nlamprian/grobot/blob/78fd627990f743997138015d14e9059079e3044f/grobot_gazebo/models/aruco_marker/model.sdf#L25-L29).

There is nothing "very elaborately tricky" about this, this is just how textures are done in Gazebo Classic. The material script and the marker image are [here](https://github.com/nlamprian/grobot/tree/master/grobot_gazebo/models/aruco_marker/materials); this should be self-explanatory.

Given you mention "older versions of Gazebo": be aware that there is 'Gazebo Classic' which typically has version *numers* and is currently at version 11, and there is 'Gazebo Sim' (i.e. 'New Gazebo') which gets version *names*, e.g. Fortress, Garden, Harmonic. Gazebo Sim used to be called 'Ignition'. This was changed to 'Gazebo Sim' due to some trademark issues wrt 'ignition'.

The material scripts work for Gazebo *Classic*, not for Gazebo *Sim*.
If you need a solution for Gazebo Sim, then [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3fJwTL2O4g) looks promising (I did not test it, but it seems to generate a `dae` model and load it as a mesh, which is indeed a possible way to load textures in Gazebo Sim).